# How can ı track files history multiple server with which user make changes this files and when usin etckeeper or similar service

Tags: git, version-control, audit

Is there a method that I can use to keep track of who made changes in certain files on several servers (with the user connected to that machine, because all users have sudo authority and everyone is root and doing so) and when?
I've tried svn and etckeeper, I can't keep track of which user has made the change in sv, and in etckeeper, commits are thrown on the root side in auto commit option, I can't follow who made the change.
When there is a change I want to make (real time or with a check in a certain time, for example once an hour)
1- The changed file and the change can be diff of the old and new version.
2- which user made that change

For example, you logged in to the server with the demo1 user with ssh and was rooted with the sudo su command, then a change was made in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.
How can I track this with etckeeper or another system including the changes made and who did it,
I already have demos with svn and etckeeper, if you have a point to ask, please feel free to ask.

Comment: If someone has superuser access, you can't *stop* them from lying about who they are and hence making commits as anyone. Your best best is probably to arrange for making it convenient for people to *not* lie about it, and maybe also *take away* superuser access (at least for anyone who abuses it), but that's not a very focused question here.

Comment: my problem is tracking  files its not abouth security or lying we trust our team but we want to logging all track for trace our mistakes and wrong confs etc. ) so if we can know wo that this change is very usefull for us